# Conflicting firestore event triggers under same location

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

This is a behavior I've just noticed in firebase cloud functions firestore triggers.

Let's say i have two firestore triggers:
**1)
document.write
/users/{userId}/offers/{offerId}/seekers/{seekerId}**
**2)
document.write
/users/{userId}/offers/{offerId}**

The second trigger executes in both cases, is it because the wild card **{offerId}** match to **seekers/{seekerId}** ?

Any help would be awesome

## askfirebase

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible for the two triggers that you've should could be fired by modifying a single document.  That's because your wildcarded paths can only identify two different documents.

In other words, a document identified by this path:

```
/users/{userId}/offers/{offerId}/seekers/{seekerId}
```

Will never be the same as a document identified by this path:

```
/users/{userId}/offers/{offerId}
```

Documents in Firestore do not "contain" other documents.  Documents in Firestore do not even "contain" other collection.  They are all completely independent of each other.  They only appear to have a relationship because of the organization you see in the console.  It is just organization for your own mental modeling.